# Pressure Equation Clarification

Tags: pressure, definition

$$\text{pressure} = \frac{\text{force}}{\text{area}}$$

Does pressure in this equation refer to the gauge pressure or absolute pressure?

Comment: It might depend on whether the force is defined as the outward normal force (giving absolute pressure) or the net normal force, outward minus inward (giving gauge pressure). I'm not sure what the convention is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we define Pressure,

```
Pressure = Force/Area.
```

That's the basic definition. Now you need to understand what is absolute pressure and gauge pressure. They refer to the value of pressure at two different points. Assume a point at depth *h* below the surface of the water*[simplest of example]* now the total pressure experienced by a body is *P*+(density)(*g*)(*Depth[h]*) i.e. the pressure applied by the liquid above the body and the atmospheric pressure.
On the contrary, absolute pressure simply means that if you calculate the pressure experienced by the body in an ***Isolated environment*** , or the pressure applied just by the liquid column above it which would be P(absolute) = (density)(g)(depth).
Hope this helps. Feel free to ask questions if any.

Vishwas